# Can't align two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am quite new to CSS and HTML so I am having trouble with aligning two divs next to each other.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>cards</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="card_container">
            <div id="card_image_container">
                <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/177482/ProfilePlaceholderSuit.png"/>
            </div>
            <div id="card_content_container">
                <div id="card_content_title">
                    <h1>ADVERT</h1>
                    <h2>EXAMPLE
                </div>
                <div id="card_content_text">
                    <p>
                    <b>Heading</b><br/>
                    Info
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <b>Heading 2</b><br/>
                    Info 2
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="card_content_actions">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#card_container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 36%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
#card_container > div{
    display: inline-block;
}
#card_image_container{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: green;
}
#card_image_container img{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#card_content_container{
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: red;
    width: 59%;
}
```

And this is the problem I have:

[white spaces around div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKCqn.png)

As you can see - my div has white spaces around it, I know this is due to 1% of width left over but if I change my:

```
#card_content_container{
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: red;
    width: 59%;
}
```

width to 60%, the content_container gets moved to next line.

I need card_content_container to fill the remaining 60% so it's aligned perfectly.

Here is js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gbcdp2on/

Comment: Remove the space between the inline block divs

Comment: @dippas the issue in this question is not the same as the dupe link. There is probbaly a question that answers this but that one is not it. This is a inline-block and white space issue

Comment: @Huangism look at the dupe questions  ;)

Comment: @dippas i have looked at it and I didn't see anywhere mentioning the space issue with inline block

Comment: @dippas I just feel like if the OP followed that link then he/she would not know why the issue existed in the first place and will simply use a different method to do this and therefore not really learning why this happened.

Comment: @Huangism it is very explicit in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) the 2nd dupe question linked, what is the problem.

Comment: @dippas the second one is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the white space between inline-block elements

Set the 59% to 60% and then update your markup to not include a space between the inline-bock elements

```
<div id="card_image_container">
     ...
</div><div id="card_content_container">
     ....
</div>
```

CSS

```
#card_content_container{
    width: 60%;
}
```

the reason the space is there when you set 60% width is because your element are inline-block, so the white space counts as a space. There are other ways to write the html if you want it to be easier to read

for example using a comment in between

```
<div id="card_image_container">
     ...
</div><!--
--><div id="card_content_container">
     ....
</div>
```

There are many ways to achieve what you want but your particular issue is the space between inline-block elements

Comment: Selected as best answer because gives a workaround using comments. Thank You all.

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements are sensitive to the white space in your code -- so just remove the white space. In your case you need to remove it between your two divs so like `</div><div id="card_content_container">`

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2x18LyLe/)**

Another option would be to float the div on the left:

```
#card_image_container {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: green;
  float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3wp1h8q5/)**

Comment: I tried float - but it breaks my parent div, it collapses it.

Comment: You can add `overflow:auto` to the parent div if using the float method.

Comment: putting </div> and <div content container> on same line worked. Thank You.

Interesting how that works, I thought new lines and tabs in editor have no effect on HTML output.

Comment: @iDooDroidoo you can set your width to 60%, your issue is with the inline-block space, check my answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox

```
#card_container {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 36%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
#card_image_container{
    flex: 4;
    background-color: green;
}
#card_content_container{
    flex: 6;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2sq6gu79/

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your parent container with `display:flex`

```css
*{
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

#card_container{
  display:flex;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 70%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 border: 1px solid grey;
}

#card_image_container{
 width: 40%;
 background-color: green;
}
#card_image_container img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#card_content_container{
 background-color: red;
 width: 60%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="card_container">
   <div id="card_image_container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/177482/ProfilePlaceholderSuit.png"/>
   </div>
   <div id="card_content_container">
    <div id="card_content_title">
     <h1>ADVERT</h1>
     <h2>EXAMPLE
    </div>
    <div id="card_content_text">
     <p>
     <b>Heading</b><br/>
     Info
     </p>
     
     <p>
     <b>Heading 2</b><br/>
     Info 2
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="card_content_actions">
    
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using flexbox.

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#card_container{
    display: flex;
  margin: auto;
    width: 36%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
#card_image_container{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: green;
}
#card_image_container img{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#card_content_container{
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: red;
    width: 60%;
}
```